# Retrieve the Outlook Office365 Flagged property through EWS

Tags: soap, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In Outlook Office365, you can flag individual mail.

[image]

Toggling this flag gives an `updated`-entry in the `SyncFolderItems`-request. This property does not seem to be part of the `Default` properties when fetching the item, or even the `AllProperties`, so I guess it is an extended property.

How do I get it through EWS? I would like to support Exchange 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [ItemSchema.Flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemschema.flag(v=exchg.80).aspx) property.

Do something like this to read such property when you use SyncFolderItems:

```
var property_set = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Flag, ItemSchema.Id);

var result = service.SyncFolderItems(folder_id, property_set, new ItemId[] { }, 10,
SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems, sync_state);


foreach (var result_item in result)
{
    var flag = result_item.Item.Flag;
}
```

The `flag` variable is of type [Flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.flag_members(v=exchg.80).aspx). Take a look at its FlagStatus member to see how to detect if the item is flagged or not.

Since this works only for Exchange 2013, here is a work around for Exchange 2010:

```
var flag_property = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090 , MapiPropertyType.Integer);

var property_set = new PropertySet(flag_property, ItemSchema.Id);

var result = service.SyncFolderItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, property_set, new ItemId[] { }, 10,
SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems, sync_state);


foreach (var result_item in result)
{
    var flag = result_item.Item.ExtendedProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyDefinition == flag_property);


    if (flag == null)
    {
        //Item is not flagged    
    }
    else if((int)flag.Value == 1)
    {
        //Item is makred complete
    }
    else if ((int)flag.Value == 2)
    {
        //Item is flagged
    }
}
```

This is based on the [PidTagFlagStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842307.aspx) property. Please note that the documentation state that this will not work for meeting or task items.

Comment: This was added in Exchange 2013 so you need to make sure your request version specifies Exchange 2013 (or greater) for it to be returned

Comment: @GlenScales Thanks guys! Is there an equivalent for Exchange 2010, since that is what I'm targeting? I'm currently storing a Boolean in a custom property, which works great, but does not work outside of my application of course.

Comment: @Tholle, please check my edited answer for a possible solution for exchange 2010.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Tried a quick SOAP request, and that worked beautifully. Just interested in mail items, so it will work great. Thank you Yacoub!